# getting error when writing the class with its constructer in the right way in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**i try to writ class with its constructer in flutter,but i am facing an error and i can't fix it...i wrote it exactly the same as the guy in the tutorial ..that is the github of the guy who wrote it and you can see the class in the file question.dart in lib folder
https://github.com/ammaralkhatib/ekhtibar_app_final.git **

```
class Qeustion {
  String questionText;
  String questionImage;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Qeustion({String q, String i, bool a}) {
    questionText = q;
    questionImage = i;
    questionAnswer = a;
  }
}
```

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Comment: So what error are you getting?

Comment: even if i write them ,i get the error @croxy

Comment: @AhamdTübingen What is that error ?

Comment: non nullable instance field questionImage must be initialized.try adding an initializer expression or add a field intialiazer in the constructer or make it 'late..the same for qeustionText and questionAnswer

Comment: @AhamdTübingen It's due to null safety. You can add `late` keyword before your variable declaration to solve `late String questionAnswer;` like that. The tutorial you are reading probably written before the null-safety support

Comment: i added it and the error is now is done ,but i have another error when i hover on q or i or a.the error says: The parameter 'q' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier. @MidhunMP

Comment: @MidhunMP No, `late` should be a last resort; it will incur runtime checks, and it will be impossible to tell if the members have been initialized.  The proper fix is to make the members nullable (or to make the constructor parameters required and to use an initializer list).

Comment: @AhamdTübingen If you want to follow whatever tutorial you're using, you should modify your `pubspec.yaml` to use `sdk: >=2.9.0 <3.0.0"` to disable null-safety.  Or better yet, read [Understanding null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).

Comment: @jamesdlin I agree that late should be the last option due to the runtime check added for every read. :+1:

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Dart supports null safety, you need mark it like this:

```
class Qeustion {
  late String questionText; // not be null
  String? questionImage;  // can be null
  late bool questionAnswer;

  Qeustion({required String q, String? i, required bool a}) {
    questionText = q;
    questionImage = i;
    questionAnswer = a;
  }
}

Qeustion qeustion = Qeustion(q: 'hello', a: true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of null safety, the tutorial you are referring won't support null safety and that's why you are getting this error. You can fix it in three ways:

**Option #1:** Use initialiser list

```
class Qeustion {
  String questionText;
  String questionImage;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Qeustion(String q, String i, bool a) : questionText = q, questionImage = i, questionAnswer = a;
}
```

Initialise it like:

```
final q = Qeustion("Q", "I", false);
```

---

**Option #2:** Use required keyword

```
class Qeustion {
  String questionText;
  String questionImage;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Qeustion({required this.questionText, required this.questionImage, required this.questionAnswer});
}
```

Initialise it like:

```
final q = Qeustion(questionText: "Q", questionImage: "I", questionAnswer: false);
```

---

**Option #3:** Mark it as late

```
class Qeustion {
  late String questionText;
  late String questionImage;
  late bool questionAnswer;

  Qeustion({String q, String i, bool a}) {
    questionText = q;
    questionImage = i;
    questionAnswer = a;
  }
}
```

Initialise it like:

```
final q = Qeustion(q: "Q", i: "I", a: false);
```

---

If you want the fields to be null, then mark it as nullable:

```
class Qeustion {
  String? questionText;
  String? questionImage;
  bool? questionAnswer;

  Qeustion({String? q, String? i, bool? a}) {
     questionText = q;
     questionImage = i;
     questionAnswer = a;
  }
}
```

Initialise it like:

```
final q = Qeustion(q: "Q", a: true); // i is null here
```

**Note:** I'll suggest you to use either option 1 or 2. Read more about [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

Answer (score 0):

**This should solve it**

```
class Question 
 {
   String? questionText;
   String? questionImage;
   bool? questionAnswer;

   Question({String? q, String? i, bool? a}) 
      {
         questionText = q;
         questionImage = i;
         questionAnswer = a;
     }
}
```